# rollup-plugin-typescript-paths не меняет пути в скомпилированном файле

Tags: typescript, импорт, path, alias, rollup

Пробую скомпилировать проект, написанный на typescript c помощью rollup с использованием плагина rollup-plugin-typescript-paths.

```
// rollup.config.js
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import multiInput from 'rollup-plugin-multi-input';
import { nodeResolve } from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import { typescriptPaths } from 'rollup-plugin-typescript-paths';

export default {
    input: ['main.ts', 'modules/a/router.ts'],
    output: {
        dir: 'dist',
        format: 'cjs'
    },
    plugins: [
        multiInput(),
        typescript(),
        typescriptPaths(),
        commonjs(),
        nodeResolve(),
    ]
};


// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "ES2015"
    ],
    "target": "ES2015",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": ".",
     "paths": {
       "@root/*": ["./*"],
     },
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}


// main.ts
import express from 'express'
import glob from 'glob'
export const app = express();

const routes = glob.sync('./modules/*/router.js')
routes.forEach(route => import(route))
app.listen(3001);


// modules/a/router.ts
import { app } from '@root/main'
app.get("/a", function (request: any, response: any) {
    response.send("<h2>Привет a</h2>");
});

export { };
```

После компиляции получаю файлы:

```
// dist/main.js
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.app = void 0;
const tslib_1 = require("tslib");
const express_1 = tslib_1.__importDefault(require("express"));
const glob_1 = tslib_1.__importDefault(require("glob"));
exports.app = express_1.default();
const routes = glob_1.default.sync('./modules/*/router.js');
routes.forEach(route => Promise.resolve().then(() => tslib_1.__importStar(require(route))));
exports.app.listen(3001);

// dist/modules/a/router.js
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const main_1 = require("@root/main");
main_1.app.get("/a", function (request, response) {
    response.send("<h2>Привет a</h2>");
});
```

Можно заметить, что в файле dist/modules/a/router.js путь @root/main так и остался неизмененным. Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте `import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve'`, и
`resolve(),` где-то до `commonjs()`.